# Spring Boot with Hibernate: Many-To-Many relationship - the entity1_has_entity2 table is empty - what is missing?

Tags: sql, spring-boot, hibernate, kotlin, many-to-many

I have 2 entities.
There is a *many to many relationship* between `band` and `product`, as a product could have many bands (like a  sampler, where many bands are on it) and a band can have many products (like shirts, cds and so on).

When I run my test (see below) it saves the 2 entities, but it doesn't save the relation between the 2 entities in the `band_has_product` table.

As far as I understood, I don't need an extra repository / entity to save the relationship into the `band_has_product` table, it should be automatically done because of all the annotations and hibernate.
Is that correct?

I'm pretty sure, I missed something, I looked in many tutorials, but I could not find what is my problem.
Looking forward for some help. Thanks

Here is the code example:

The `product` entity is created like this:

```
@Entity
data class Product(

    @Id
    @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Schema(hidden = true)
    val id: Int? = null,

    var name: @NotEmpty(message = "name must not be empty") String? = null,

    ) {
    @JsonBackReference(value ="bands")
    @ManyToMany( fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
        mappedBy = "products",
    )
    var bands: MutableSet<Band> = mutableSetOf()

}
```

while the band entity looks like this:

```
@Entity
data class Band(

    @Id
    @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Schema(hidden = true)
    val id: Int? = null,

    var name: @NotEmpty(message = "name must not be empty") String? = null,

    var description: String? = null,
){
    @JsonBackReference(value ="products")
    @ManyToMany(
        fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
        cascade = [CascadeType.ALL])
    @JoinTable(
        name = "band_has_product",
        joinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "band_id")],
        inverseJoinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "product_id")]
    )
    var products: MutableSet<Product> = mutableSetOf()
}
```

the band is created like this:

```
create table band
(
    id serial PRIMARY KEY not null,
    name varchar(100) not null,
    description text

);
```

and the product is created like this:

```
create table product
(
    id serial PRIMARY KEY not null,
    name varchar(100) not null
);
```

I wrote a test to test this. Band and product is saved, but the auto generated `band_has_product` table is empty

```
@Test
fun `creating Product should be saved in the DB`() {
    var bandSaved1 = bandRepository!!.save(BandUtils.createBandWithoutLinks("band1"))

    productRepository!!.save(ProductUtils.createProductWithBand(
        bandSaved1,"product1"))

    val bands = (bandRepository!!.findAll() as Collection<Band>)
    val products = (productRepository!!.findAll() as Collection<Product>)


    bands.size shouldBe 1  // TRUE
    products.size shouldBe 1  // TRUE

    // not true, as the band_has_product table is empty
    val product = products.first().bands shouldContain bandSaved1
```

The Test helper functions look like this:

```
fun createBandWithoutLinks(name: String = BAND_NAME_WITHOUT_LINK): Band {
        val band = Band()
        band.name = name
        band.description = "merch em all"
        return band
  }

fun createProductWithBand(band: Band,
                          name: String = PRODUCT_NAME): Product {
    var product = Product(
        name = name,
    )
    product.bands.add(band)
    return product
}
```

The repositories are normal CrudRepos:

```
@Repository
interface BandRepository : CrudRepository<Band?, Int?> {}

@Repository
interface ProductRepository : CrudRepository<Product?, Int?> {}
```

and I use the standard save functions.

the `MainApp` looks like this:

```
@EnableJpaRepositories
@SpringBootApplication
class MainApp

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<MainApp>(*args)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading "[Java persistence with JPA and Hibernate, Part 2: Many-to-many relationships](https://www.infoworld.com/article/3387643/java-persistence-with-jpa-and-hibernate-part-2-many-to-many-relationships.html)" from [Steven Haines](https://www.linkedin.com/in/stevenhaines/), you can see that, in a Many-to-Many relationship with JPA and Hibernate, you need to properly manage both sides of the relationship.

For instance, in your test helper function `createProductWithBand`:

```kotlin
fun createProductWithBand(band: Band, name: String = PRODUCT_NAME): Product {
    var product = Product(
        name = name,
    )
    product.bands.add(band)
    return product
}
```

In this function, a `Product` is being created and a `Band` is added to its `bands` collection. However, the reverse is not happening; the `Product` is not being added to the `Band`'s `products` collection.

And your test function:

```kotlin
@Test
fun `creating Product should be saved in the DB`() {
    var bandSaved1 = bandRepository!!.save(BandUtils.createBandWithoutLinks("band1"))

    productRepository!!.save(ProductUtils.createProductWithBand(bandSaved1,"product1"))

    // ...
}
```

Here, a `Band` is being saved and then a `Product` is created with that `Band` and saved. However, at no point in the code is the `Product` added to the `Band`'s `products` collection.

This means that only one side of the relationship is being set (i.e., the `Product` knows about the `Band`, but the `Band` does not know about the `Product`).

In a bidirectional relationship like this one, you must update both sides of the relationship. The JPA provider (Hibernate in this case) needs to know about the relationship from both sides in order to properly update the join table (`band_has_product`).

```kotlin
fun createProductWithBand(band: Band, name: String = PRODUCT_NAME): Product {
    var product = Product(
        name = name,
    )
    product.bands.add(band)

    // Also set the reverse relationship
    band.products.add(product)

    return product
}
```

By doing this, when you save the `Product`, Hibernate will know that it is associated with a `Band`, and likewise, when you save the `Band`, Hibernate will know it is associated with a `Product`. This will ensure that the join table `band_has_product` is populated correctly.

---

From the OP's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76608400/6309), I can add that in Kotlin, the `plus` function returns a new list that includes the element being added, but it does not modify the original list. Therefore, when you call `band.products.size` again, it will still be 0 because the original list has not been modified.

To correctly update the `products` collection of the `Band` entity, you can assign the result of `plus` back to the `products` property of the `Band`. This will update the `products` collection with the new product added.

That would be, based on your approach:

```kotlin
@Test
fun `creating Product should be saved in the DB`() {
    var bandSaved = bandRepository!!.save(BandUtils.createBandWithoutLinks("band1"))

    var product = ProductUtils.createProductWithBand(bandSaved, "product1")
    bandSaved.products = bandSaved.products.plus(product)  // Update the products collection

    val productSaved = productRepository!!.save(product)

    val bands = (bandRepository!!.findAll() as Collection<Band>)
    val products = (productRepository!!.findAll() as Collection<Product>)

    bands.size shouldBe 1  // TRUE
    products.size shouldBe 1  // TRUE

    val product = products.first().bands shouldContain bandSaved
}
```

And the modified helper function:

```kotlin
fun createProductWithBand(band: Band, name: String = PRODUCT_NAME): Product {
    var product = Product(name = name)
    product.bands = product.bands.plus(band)  // Update the bands collection
    return product
}
```

By assigning the result of `plus` back to the `products` and `bands` collections, you are updating the collections with the new entity, and the changes will be persisted correctly.

Since the code now directly modifies the collections, you are no longer required to use `@Transactional` explicitly in this specific scenario.
However, do note that in a more complex scenario or a real-world application, using transactions may still be necessary to ensure data consistency and atomicity of operations.

---

[Nathan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2561541/nathan) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76592773/spring-boot-with-hibernate-many-to-many-relationship-the-entity1-has-entity2/76602767#comment135060871_76602767):

> For the purposes of a write operation, adding the product to the `bank` is the only one that matters. The `@ManyToMany` annotation with the `mappedBy=""` is used when loading but not when persisting or updating.
>
> In a test, if you want it to be loaded correctly, you may need to have a manual flush, evict, or refresh in order to correctly load the `mappedBy=""` if you only set one side.
> At least, this is all how things worked in hibernate 3.x, 4x, und 5.x. Don't have much experience with 6. But I would assume that this didn't change in 6.

It is true that, here, the `Band` entity is the owning side of the relationship (because it does not use the `mappedBy` attribute), and the `Product` entity is the inverse side (because it uses the `mappedBy` attribute).

When testing, if you make a change on the inverse side of the relationship (`Product` in this case) and you want it to be reflected immediately in the session cache, you might need to manually flush the session to the database and refresh the entity. This is because Hibernate might not synchronize the changes to the database until the transaction is committed.

```kotlin
@Test
@Transactional
fun `creating Product should be saved in the DB`() {
    var band = BandUtils.createBandWithoutLinks("band1")
    var product = ProductUtils.createProductWithBand(band, "product1")

    // Save the band (owning side of the relationship)
    band = bandRepository!!.save(band)

    // Save the product (inverse side of the relationship)
    product = productRepository!!.save(product)

    // Flush changes immediately to the database
    entityManager.flush()

    // Refresh the product entity to reflect the changes
    entityManager.refresh(product)

    val bands = (bandRepository!!.findAll() as Collection<Band>)
    val products = (productRepository!!.findAll() as Collection<Product>)

    bands.size shouldBe 1  // TRUE
    products.size shouldBe 1  // TRUE

    // Now it should be true as both sides of the relationship are set
    val product = products.first().bands shouldContain band
}
```

Warning: the `entityManager` should be autowired into the test class for this to work.

That practice is generally more common in tests.
In production code, it's usually not necessary to force a flush or refresh within the same transaction, as the changes will be automatically synchronized at the end of the transaction.

---

You also need to ensure that the operations are performed within a transaction. This is because, in JPA, the persistence context is often flushed to the database at the end of the transaction.
See also  "[JPA/Hibernate Persistence Context](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-hibernate-persistence-context)" from [Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/about)

```kotlin
@Test
@Transactional  // Ensure the entire method is run within a single transaction
fun `creating Product should be saved in the DB`() {
    var band = BandUtils.createBandWithoutLinks("band1")
    var product = ProductUtils.createProductWithBand(band, "product1")

    // Save both the band and the product
    band = bandRepository!!.save(band)
    product = productRepository!!.save(product)

    val bands = (bandRepository!!.findAll() as Collection<Band>)
    val products = (productRepository!!.findAll() as Collection<Product>)

    bands.size shouldBe 1  // TRUE
    products.size shouldBe 1  // TRUE

    // Now it should be true as both sides of the relationship are set
    val product = products.first().bands shouldContain band
}
```

That should make sure that when you save a `Product`, the corresponding bands are saved and vice versa, and the relationships are stored in the `band_has_product` table.

That uses a transaction-scoped persistence context, the default type of persistence context in JPA when working with a Java EE or Spring environment.

The `@Transactional` annotation ensures that the entire method is run within a single transaction. It means that a persistence context is created at the start of the method, and any changes made to the entities are tracked within this persistence context.
When the method completes, the transaction is either committed or rolled back, and the persistence context is closed. At this point, any changes made to the managed entities within the transaction are flushed to the database.

That type of persistence context is appropriate for the provided scenario, where you want to save entities and their relationships in a single atomic operation, ensuring data consistency.

Comment: oh.. you are right. I'm not adding the product back into band. I will check this out later and accept it afterwards. Thanks a lot for this tip

Comment: For the purposes of a write operation, adding the product to the bank is the only one that matters. The @ManyToMany annotation with the mappedBy="" is used when loading but not when persisting or updating. In a test, if you want it to be loaded correctly, you may need to have a manual flush, evict, or refresh in order to correctly load the mappedBy="" if you only set one side. At least, this is all how things worked in hibernate 3.x, 4x, und 5.x. Don't have much experience with 6. But I would assume that this didn't change in 6.x

Comment: @Nathan Good point, thank you for your feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility, and added the relevant associated test.

Comment: my only problem was really the not putting it back. then it works without the transactional
(at least the adding)

Comment: @Joergi True. I keep the transactional part just for educational purpose (mine included).

Comment: but I will need the EntityManager for deleting it properly.
but yeah, I'm happy that I made no mistake in the many to many relationship... I was just stupid not adding it back again. Thanks for your help @Nathan and VonC